# Create a nodejs image with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am following this documentation

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

If you follow the docs this is the dockerfile you get at end of the section.

```
C:\Users\dynode\node-cluster>
```

I have the nodejs project in this directory , where should I create my dockerfile and `"WORKDIR /usr/src/app"` what change should be made to this so I can move forward

Answer (score 0):

Put your Dockerfile at `C:\Users\dynode\node-cluster\Dockerfile`.

Do not change the path for the `WORKDIR` - that is a path *inside* the container.

The only relevant paths you need to worry about are the `COPY` ones, which will both work as-is since they are relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile should be created next to the node.js source code. This can be inferred from the paths being used to add the source code into the Docker image.

As you can see, `COPY package*.json ./`, would imply that the Dockerfile is next to the `package.json` file.

As for `/usr/src/app`, this path is not on your machine, but rather inside the container and the Dockerfile is creating this folder inside the image. So nothing to do here.